White Screen When Deploying React JS Build on AWS Amplify
he Problem:
I'm encountering a recurring issue with my React application deployed on AWS Amplify. After deployment, the app initially displays a white screen, and additional manual changes are required to make it work.
Setup:
Hosting Platform: AWS Amplify Frontend Framework: React.js Version Control: Bitbucket
Steps to Reproduce:
Merge a branch into master, triggering an automatic deployment on AWS Amplify. After deployment, accessing the app results in a white screen. To resolve, I modify the Rewrites and Redirects rules: Change the rule from 200 to 404 and redeploy. After redeployment, the app loads successfully. However, refreshing any page causes the white screen to reappear. I must then revert the rule back from 404 to 200 and redeploy again to fix it. This cycle repeats with every new deployment.
What I’ve Tried:
Adjusting Rewrites and Redirects to manage the issue temporarily. Ensuring my react-router-dom setup includes proper configuration. Any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
My Questions:
Can AWS Amplify automatically handle this without requiring manual changes in the redirect rules after each deployment? Why does refreshing a page trigger this issue, and how can I avoid it entirely?

By default, AWS Amplify may not know how to serve the correct files when using a client-side routing framework like React Router. That's why you had to manually change the rules. However, by configuring the correct rewrite rule as described above, you can automate the handling of routes and eliminate the need for manual intervention after every deployment.

But the thing is it should be automatic. I have to do it all the time.
Merge Master> Change Rule> Redeploy> Change Rule

Possibly a CloudFront cache invalidation issue... Does your app have new generated js/css filenames on each build?
